# How to assign value to left side using Overload operator[]?

Tags: c++, operator-overloading

I have made the following code:-

```
class A{
     bool bFlag[2];
public:
  A(){
      for(int  i = 0; i < 2; i++)
          bFlag[i] = false;
  }

  bool operator[](int r){ //i know how to assign value to R.H.S using operator[]
      if( r >= 0 || r < 2 ){
          bFlag[r] = true;
          return bFlag[r];
   }
   return false;        
  }   
};

int main(){
    A obj;
    bool x;
    x = obj[0]; //this i know
    //obj[1] = x; //how to do this is my doubt?
    return 0;
}
```

I dont know to set value to `L.H.S` using `operator[]`. 
Please guide me to how to set `x` value to `obj[1]`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Als is right, but here is an example:

```
class A{
private:
    int val[10];
public:
    A(){}
    int& operator[](int i) {
        return val[i];
    }
};
```

this makes in posible to do things like

```
A a;
a[2] = 2;
```

you should of course add the old method as well. to optimize for l-value to making it.

```
class A{
private:
    int val[10];
public:
    A(){}
    const int operator[](int i) const {
        return val[i];
    }
    int& operator[](int i) {
        return val[i];
    }
};
```

Comment: Thanks a lot. This was my next doubt and u have given solution before that.

Answer (score 5):

To use `[]` as an lvalue your overloaded `[]` should return by reference.

***Is it okay to return reference to a private member?***
**Yes**, It is perfectly fine.
Most of the STL classes do that if you see the STL.
The rule is you should return a `const` reference to your private member if you do not wish the user to modify the contents there or if you want to allow users to modify it you can return a `non const` reference.

You basically hide(Abstract) the details of your class from the user of class by making them `private`, but you still provide the functionality to be able to modify individual elements.

Comment: But here `bFlag` is a private data member. Can we put reference to private data members?

Comment: abhineet, to answer your comment: "yes" :-)